# Out-of-order Hardware: How "smart" is it?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86-64, low-level, order-of-execution

I'm working on an incredibly performance-critical project where every clock cycle counts in my most important inner loop.  I'm thinking about restructuring the code to hide instruction latencies, but I'm wondering to what extent modern CPUs' out-of-order execution hardware already does this for me.  Consider the following (simple, hypothetical) example:

```
// Increment three counters.  These instructions should all execute in
// parallel with latency of one cycle.  Assume the previous register values
// have been computed a long time ago and are ready to use by the time
// these are decoded.
add RAX, 1;
add RBX, 2;
add RCX, 3;

// Multiply takes at least three cycles.  Again, assume both inputs are
// ready by the time we get here.
imul RDX, RDI;

// Use the result of the imul immediately in a long dependency chain.
mov RDX, [RDX];
cmp RDX, 1;
jae LBlahBlahBlah;
```

My question is which of the following applies:

- Modern mainstream out-of-order hardware will reorder the `imul` before the three `add` instructions even though the `add` instructions come before the `imul` programmatically and have all of their input dependencies available by the time they're decoded.  The `imul` has a longer latency than the `add` instructions and is used immediately in a dependency chain, so this is optimal.
- Out-of-order execution only happens when the programmatically earlier instructions *can't* be executed when they're decoded due to missing input dependencies.  The hardware can't be expected to "look ahead" to optimize things like this on the fly.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I would guess it varies based on the actual CPU and particular instructions involved. A compiler, though, would certainly make this kind of optimization for you.

Comment: You'll find that modern x86 hardware is *very* capable of reordering things over large distances and across loop iterations provided that there are no branch mispredictions.

Answer (score 2):

Your second interpretation is correct, the idea behind out-of-order execution is to ensure long dependency chains or other long-running instructions (like memory accesses) do not block independent operations (like an add between two registers unrelated to the long-running instruction) and allow them to execute in parallel. However, instructions are fetched and decoded in-order. The processor cannot look ahead into the program, decide that an instruction is an independent one and run it before even retrieving the others. That is where the compiler is suppose to optimize.

In your example, the instructions are fetched and decoded in sequence, first `add RAX, 1`, then `add RBX, 2`, then `add RCX, 3` and then `imul RDX, RDI` (though you could fetch and decode multiple ones if the processor is superscaler, but that is a separate concept). Each would be dispatched to the proper reservation station in turn, however, the out-of-order aspect would come that if there is just one unit to perform additions, the some adds might execute at the same time as the `imul`; this is VERY architecture depend.

If the details of time requirements are so strict, you will want to be extremely careful with modern, high-speed architectures, as they have a large number of complex structures to improve performance. However, depending on the code run, these mechanisms could result in significant latencies. Branch prediction and caching are just two sources of delays in the event of a miss or misprediction (or nice throughput improvements when used properly). Your best bet is to get a cycle-accurate simulator of the processor to ensure your code will meet the requirements (Or you could use the actual hardware potentially).

Also note, if you are using a modern architecture, I assume you might have an OS running, which is a level of software that will destroy the super high performance you are attempting to attain.

Comment: There are no scalar out-of-order x86 CPUs.  They're always at least 2-wide (Bulldozer-family's integer cores, Silvermont), and more commonly 4-wide (Intel Core 2 through Skylake).  Or 5-wide (Ryzen).  So most modern x86 CPUs could issue all 4 uops into the out-of-order back-end in the same cycle, and dispatch all 4 of them to execution units in the next cycle.  (Assuming it didn't schedule one of the multiples to the only port `imul` can run on...  **[How are x86 uops scheduled, exactly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40681331)**).

Comment: But yes, after issue, they dispatch in oldest-ready-first order.  After the first loop iteration or so, this *often* prioritizes the critical path that's blocking retirement, but putting the critical path uops sooner is probably usually better especially in non-looping code, or if it won't run many iterations.